# What is the upper age limit for a master's degree program in Germany?

Tags: masters, funding, germany, age

I have a bachelor in electronics engineering, and I am 32 years old. I belong to a South Asian country and I want to apply for a master's degree program in Germany. But am I agewise eligible?

I have tried to explore different master's degree programs on https://www.daad.de/en/, but I couldn't find any information about an age limit.

Comment: Other than funding issues, some countries are reluctant to issue student visas to older applicants.

Comment: The question is tagged funding, but the text does not mention this. Is funding (from the university / German government) a requirement for you?

Answer (score 25):

There is no age limit for studying in Germany. In fact, it is not that uncommon for students to be as old as you (or even significantly older) when starting or continuing with university. A C1 language level might often be a requirement, though.

**EDIT**: As the question is tagged "funding" (which I did not notice when first answering), I want to add: on the DAAD website, there is some information on requirements for scholarships. They state that in most cases, there is no age limit for scholarships either, but in some cases there is a maximum amount of time that is allowed to have passed since the last degree (e.g. maximum of 5 years after the completion of the BA at the time of application).

Comment: There are quite a large number of Masters in many subjects taught in English, as well, if German is a problem

Comment: He's asking about FUNDING though, i.e. scholarships. A lot of them do have age limits.

Comment: The question is _tagged_ funding, but funding and scholarships aren't mentioned in the body or title.

Comment: As an example, the "information systems" master at the Technical University of Munich is completely in English - no C1 German language level necessary.

Comment: Note that Germany has wide-reaching anti-age-discrimination laws which I believe (IANAL) would apply to all funding opportunities as well as the masters itself.

Comment: @JackAidley I believe that you can sue your way into a study program (people have already sucessfully done that), but not into funding, as this is not universally available in the first place (only to a select few).

Answer (score 10):

Definitely no age limit for most places - we have students in their 50s.